# Motorcycle Starting Issue - no longer starting after attempting to jump with a car battery

Tags: electrical, motorcycle, battery, ignition, jump-start

I tried jump start my bike with my car battery because the motorcycle battery was really low and would not start. I mistakenly touched both ends of the jump leads together and cause a big spark, suddenly the bike died and the ignition not coming on at all.

What can I do to get it working again?

Comment: Can you provide the make/model/year of the bike?  Can also add in as much detail as you can to your question?  how the leads were hooked up.....positive/neg on bike battery were hooked up when this happened or from the car....or....just explain the configuration as detailed as possible.  You should get some good suggestions or possible ideas on what happened if you do.  Just a bit more data....thanks   :)

Comment: Make/model/year?

Answer (score 5):

In the circuit that contains your starter relay there is a fuse, typically it is a 30amp fuse.

Here is an image a Yamaha R1 starter relay fuse

[image]

Depending on your model of motorcycle you will need to:

1. Discover the location of your relay fuse
2. Remove a plastic cover for the relay
3. Possibly, remove a plastic cover for the fuse.
4. Remove and Replace old fuse
5. Reassemble
6. Start your bike

There is a very high percentage that your motorcycle is just fine and that this is the issue.  Nothing to panic about.